# KDE Plasma 5 and Kali linux 2.0 Problem

Tags: kde, kali-linux, desktop, plasma, kde5

I can not install the desktop ' KDE Plasma 5' in my Kali Linux , but if I can install ' KDE 4 '. I want to install KDE Plasma 5.

My list of repositories:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2.0 _Sana_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150811-09:06]/ sana contrib main non-free 
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2.0 _Sana_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150811-09:06]/ sana contrib main non-free

# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free


deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free


# For source package access, uncomment the following line
 deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
 deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

I followed these steps

```
 apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base kde-plasma-desktop
```

[image: After the command]

Finally install ... :(

[image]

But I want to install this version KDE 5.

Comment: Your sentence "I saw that if you can install the version 5 ." is incomplete/does not make sense. Please edit your post to make clear what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using these repositories:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

KDE 5 is not present there, because Kali does not support it for some reason. [Debian does not support it yet](https://wiki.debian.org/es/KDE).

If you want install KDE5, use any other repositorie or check links like this:

http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/03/kde-plasma-56-beta-released-compile-on.html